# Polymer Scaffolding : Setting Title per page : Best approach

Tags: polymer

Our team is building our first polymer all in one page app and we kind of have to reverse engineer a neglected component of the project.  We need to set the title for the title bar in the core-scaffolding. This is easy on simple pages by using JS, however some pages have conditional templates that show content and each require their own titles.

eg

```
<core-scaffolding>
<div id="title">Dynamic Title goes here</div>
<core-animated-pages transitions="cross-fade">
  <section>
   <div cross-fade>
<my-element>
<template if="{{condition1}}"></template>
Content 1
</template>

<template if="{{condition2}}"></template>
Content 2
</template>

<template if="{{condition3}}"></template>
Content 3
</template>
</my-element>
</div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div cross-fade></div>
  </section>
</core-animated-pages>
```

I was going to add an attribute on the template elements to be able to pass a title value, however I don't know how to use JS to find out which template is the one that is conditionally rendered (active).  I can't seem to find any documentation on this. Also I want to build something reusable (not with IDs) that can be used globally on any page.

Can anyone provide any suggestions?

Cheers,
david

Answer (score 0):

i don't think i would use conditional template for this. if that condition changes a lot the content of the template will be added and removed from the dom every time it is changed. i think it would be better to use the hidden attribute or use databinding to change the text dynamically.

hidden attribute

```
<span hidden?="{{!condition1}}">Content 1</span>
<span hidden?="{{!condition2}}">Content 2</span>
<span hidden?="{{!condition2}}">Content 3</span>
```

databinding

```
<span>{{content}}</span>
```

then you can change the databind in javascript like normal.

```
if (condition1) {
  this.content = 'Content 1';
}
```